# Server directory bruteforcing

Tags: brute-force, server

Recently I saw hundreds of strange requests from different ip addresses in my server logs.

These requests were trying to bruteforce directories for example:

```
GET /admin/admin.php 404
GET /admin/controlpanel.html 404
GET /admin/controlpanel.php 404
GET /admin/controlpanel.asp 404
```

Also some requests contained some JavaScript and PHP code.

What I should do in such situations?

Comment: "Welcome to the Internet"- you will get this type of thing every day you are exposed to the internet. What do you do? Make sure your server is secure against such attacks.

Comment: Search here for "strange logs" and you'll see there are many people asking similar things.

Comment: @schroeder my server is secure against such attacks but these requests were continiously being sent so it reduced server's performance. I can block these addresses but ip's also changes.

Comment: These aren't "attacks". They are just abnormal requests. You have a performance engineering problem, not a security problem. A CDN tends to be the recommended tool to be more resilient to invalid requests